# слово «МИНИМУМ» надо преобразовать его в «МИНИ.У

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

//Например, слово «МИНИМУМ» надо преобразовать в «МИНИ.У.» т.е. взять первый символ строки а после все его вхождения в строку заменить на точки

```
s="МИНИМУМ"
s=s.replace(/.М{2,}/,"."))//нужно подправить
```

Comment: А как именно нужно изменить слово? Вы так задали вопрос, будто нужно написать `s="МИНИ.У."` . Конкретизируйте вопрос

Comment: Нельзя сказать регулярному выражению, чтобы оно изменило строку так, как вы говорите, просто с потолка. Нужен хоть какой-нибудь принцип. Например, заменить в последних трёх буквах буквы "М" на точки, или заменить "МУМ" на ".У.", или заменить все повторяющиеся символы в какой-то части слова. Хоть что-нибудь конкретное есть в вашей задаче?

Comment: Один вариант вам уже предложили: `s="МИНИ.У."`, второй (через регулярку): `s="МИНИМУМ".replace(/(.+?)М/g,"$1.")`, но ведь через регулярку можно было и так заменить: `s="МИНИМУМ".replace(/МИНИМУМ/g, "МИНИ.У.")`, поэтому надо уточнить что и как вы хотите сделать (чтобы по вашему описанию это можно было ручками проделать)

Comment: @BOPOH, @ PloadyFree  я вас понял,поправил описание темы

Comment: В `js` регулярки очень кастрированные. Думаю, не получится. На `php` можно попробовать, там можно делать рекурсивные подзапросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одной регуляркой не обойтись, их функционал в `js` обрезан по самое не хочу. Можно сделать так. Сохраним первый символ строки в `needle`, и потом заменим все символы в строке, кроме первого:

```js
string = "МИНИМУМ";
needle = string[0];
regexp = new RegExp("(?!^)"+needle, 'g');
alert(string.replace(regexp, '.'));
```

Comment: `string = "[а вот так?]";` и крышка этому коду.

Answer (score 2):

Одной заменой на js сделать невозможно, поскольку не поддерживается предпросмотр назад. Однако, если бы надо было убрать последние символы, то это можно было бы сделать.

Возможный вариант тошлько при помощи регулярок:

1. Копируем первый символ в конец.
2. Удаляем все символы, равные последнему, кроме первого.
3. Удаляем последний символ.

Вот этот и похожий вариант в виде кода:

```
"МИНИМУМ".replace(/^(.).*/,"$&$1").replace(/(?!^)(.)(?=.*\1$)/g,".").replace(/.$/,"")
"МИНИМУМ".replace(/(.)(.*)/,"$2$1").replace(/(.)(?=.*\1$)/g,".").replace(/(.*)(.)/,"$2$1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Одной чистой регуляркой я не нашёл способа это сделать, но почти уверен, что такой есть.
Я могу предложить следующее:

```
var s = "МИНИМУМ";
var c = s.charAt(0);
s = c + s.substring(1).split(c).join(".");
```

Comment: C каких пор `replaceAll` есть в js?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я использовал jjs. Вы можете предложить другой вариант?

Comment: Пара split/join, как вариант. А про регулярки сейчас отвечу.

Comment: @PloadyFree, можно использовать мою регулярку из комента, подставив туда заменяемый символ через `charAt(0)`

Comment: @BOPOH, не надо подставлять в регулярки символы, не проверяя необходимость экранирования.

Comment: `.split(c).join(".")`

Answer (score 1):

Без использования регулярных выражений:

```
Array.prototype.map.call("МИНИМУМ", function (ch, i, s) {
  return !i || ch !== s[0] ? ch : ".";
}).join("")
```

Comment: Мне кажется стоит упомянуть про совместимость со старыми браузерами. Ваше решение не будет работать в IE8-

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да, для старых браузеров можно заменить обращение по индексу к строке на вызов charAt и подключить полифил для map.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно в js появился предпросмотр назад, так что если его поддержка устраивает, то можно так:

```js
console.log("МИНИМУМ".replace(/(?!^)(.)(?<=^\1.*)/g, "."))
```